# Where did this Hadith come from?

Tags: source-identification

There is a hadith I heard that said: Whoever listens to music, molten rock will be poured into his ears on Youmul Qyamah.  Where is this Hadith recorded? and what is it's authenticity?

Oh, and I also already checked Sunnah.com and it's not there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you mean is probably this one:

> من جلس إلى قينة صب في أذنه الآنك يوم القيامة.
>
> He who sits (and listens) to a singer will have molten lead poured
>   into his ears in the day of judgement.

The authenticity of this hadith is highly suspect and is considered by most scholars as *mawduu* (false). Following link is a fatwa in Arabic regarding it:

http://www.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=151267

Answer (score 7):

A hadith similar to the one you're looking for is collected by Ibn 'Asakir on the authority of Anas (ra). Al-Albani classified it as maudu' (fabricated) in Da'if al-Jami' as-Saghir #5410 (I checked the attribution to Al-Albani myself):

> من استمع قينة صب في أذنيه الآنك يوم القيامة
>
> "Whoever listens to a female singer, molten lead will be poured into his ears on the Day of Judgement."